# How to read u-boot environmental variables in kernel driver code

Tags: linux, u-boot

bootcmd is a u-boot environmental variable.

I have to read that variable in kernel driver code

The driver is kernel_imx/drivers/input/keyboard/gpio_keys.c

How can I access?

Comment: did you read about the [fw_printenv](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/fw_printenv.8.html) command ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not.  You use one of the defined interfaces, such as the device tree, to pass information from the bootloader to the kernel.